# Nesting for loop automatic

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a array with objects and those objects consist of some arrays. I wanna loop through the entire array and the array inside the objects. Sound complicated but if you look at the example below it works. However my problem is that right now the length of the variables array is 2, but how can i implement something that makes this type of loop in loop possible if the array is length 4 without hardcoding it since I will get data from a api that varies a lot on the variables.

```js
let wantedArray =[]
let array = [
  { gender: male, value: 10, age: 5,countryofbirth:"Norway" },
  { gender: female, value: 10, age: 2,countryofbirth:"Sweden" },
{ gender: male, value: 15, age: 3,countryofbirth:"Norway" },
{ gender: male, value: 11, age: 4,countryofbirth:"Norway" },
{ gender: female, value: 10, age: 2,countryofbirth:"Finland" },
  ...
]
let variables = [
  { id: gender, options: [male, female] },
  { id: "countryofbirth",  options: ["Norway", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Finland"]}
]
variables[0].options.map((item) => {
  variables[1].options.map((item2) => {
    let currArray = array.filter((currData) =>
      currData[variables[0].id] === item &&
      currData[variables[1].id] === item2);

//lets say that it have come to the point in the loop where item===male and item2==="Norway"

    let currObject ={variables[0].id:item//"Male",
variables[1].id:item2}//"Norway"
let currValues ={}
    currArray.map((data)=>{
    currValues[data.age]=value
})
currObject["values"]=currValues
wantedArray.push(currObject)
/*This means when item===male and item2==="Norway" the function would push {
gender:"Male",
countryofbirth:"Norway,
values:{5:10,3:15,4:11}
} to wantedArray*/
  })
})
```

Comment: You need to start by looping through the `array` first.

Comment: You should specify what you want to achieve as a final result more than how you are trying to achieve that since to me it looks like it doesn't make much sense the filtering part you are doing.

Comment: What is the end result you're looking for, here? Those `.map`s should be `forEach`es, only the last invocation of `.filter` ends up doing anything...

Comment: Also, the names `gender`, `age`, `male` and `female` are undefined. Should they maybe be strings?

Comment: @CesarePolonara I edited the question to better describe what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @AKX I edited the question to better describe what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, to me that's even less clear. Take your time to think about what's the end result you want to achieve and abstract the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're maybe looking for something like

```
const data = [
  {gender: "male", value: 10, age: 5, countryofbirth: 'Norway'},
  {gender: "female", value: 10, age: 2, countryofbirth: 'Sweden'},
  {gender: "male", value: 15, age: 3, countryofbirth: 'Norway'},
  {gender: "male", value: 11, age: 4, countryofbirth: 'Norway'},
  {gender: "female", value: 10, age: 2, countryofbirth: 'Finland'},
]

// These are all dynamic.
const filter = {gender: "male", countryofbirth: 'Norway'};
const valueKey = 'age';
const valueValue = 'value';

// Find objects with key/values matching all of those in `filter`.
const matching = data.filter((item) => Object.entries(filter).every(([key, value]) => item[key] === value));
console.log(matching);

// Generate a mapping from the found objects using the `valueKey` and `valueValue` variables.
const values = Object.fromEntries(matching.map((item) => [item[valueKey], item[valueValue]]));

// Merge the filter and the values to get the desired result.
console.log({...filter, values});
```

which finally prints out

```
{
  gender: 'male',
  countryofbirth: 'Norway',
  values: { '3': 15, '4': 11, '5': 10 }
}
```